# How delete data from other table - WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cascading

I am trying to delete data from another table using before_delete_post. However, my script does not work. My before_delete_post is at the top of the code. The effect I would like to get when deleting a post would be to delete the data from another table(wp_used_cars) with the same id.

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'my_func' );
function my_func( $postid ){

    global $post_type;   
    if ( $post_type != 'my_custom_post_type' ) return;

    $post_type->query( $wpdb->prepare( 'DELETE FROM wp_used_cars WHERE post_id = %d', $postid ) );
}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// add custom posts --------------------------------------------------------

// add uzywane custom post and set custom capabilities
$uzywane = new CustomPost('uzywane');
$uzywane->make('Uzywane', 'Uzywane', 'Uzywane', array(
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post'             => 'edit_used_car',
        'read_post'             => 'read_used_car',
        'delete_post'           => 'delete_used_car',
        'edit_posts'            => 'edit_used_cars',
        'edit_others_posts'     => 'edit_others_used_cars',
        'publish_posts'         => 'publish_used_cars',
        'read_private_posts'    => 'read_private_used_cars',
    ),
));

// add this custom capabilities to admin
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_used_car', true );
$role->add_cap( 'read_used_car', true );
$role->add_cap( 'delete_used_car', true );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_used_cars', true );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_others_used_cars', true );
$role->add_cap( 'publish_used_cars', true );
$role->add_cap( 'read_private_used_cars', true );

// if role uzywane don't exists add it and set capabilities to edit uzywane
if( ! role_exists( 'uzywane' ) ) {
    add_role(
        'uzywane',
        __( 'Używane' ),
        array(
            'read'                  => true,
            'edit_used_car'         => true,
            'read_used_car'         => true,
            'delete_used_car'       => true,
            'edit_used_cars'        => true,
            'edit_others_used_cars' => true,
            'publish_used_cars'     => true,
            'read_private_used_cars'=> true,
            'unfiltered_upload'     => true,
            'upload_files'          => true,
            'edit_posts'            => true,
        )
    );
}

// if user has role uzywane than remove links from admin panel
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'uzywane', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    function remove_links() {
        echo '<style>.menu-icon-post, .menu-icon-promo_posts, .menu-icon-serwis, .menu-icon-nowe, .menu-icon-silniki, .menu-icon-comments, #toplevel_page_wpcf7, .menu-icon-tools, #wp-admin-bar-new-content, #wp-admin-bar-wpseo-menu, #wp-admin-bar-comments, .update-nag {display: none;}</style>';
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'remove_links');
}


// if role uzywane don't exists add it and set capabilities to edit uzywane
if( ! role_exists( 'uzywane-admin' ) ) {
    add_role(
        'uzywane-admin',
        __( 'Używane-admin' ),
        array(
            'read'                  => true,
            'edit_used_car'         => true,
            'read_used_car'         => true,
            'delete_used_car'       => true,
            'edit_used_cars'        => true,
            'edit_others_used_cars' => true,
            'publish_used_cars'     => true,
            'read_private_used_cars'=> true,
            'unfiltered_upload'     => true,
            'upload_files'          => true,
            'edit_posts'            => true,
            'edit_others_posts'     => true,
            'manage_options'        => true,
        )
    );
}

// if user has role uzywane than remove links from admin panel
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'uzywane-admin', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    function remove_links() {
        echo '<style> #toplevel_page_revslider, #toplevel_page_revslider, #menu-settings, #toplevel_page_wpseo_dashboard, #toplevel_page_edit-post_type-search-filter-widget, #toplevel_page_easy-responsive-tabs, .menu-icon-post, .menu-icon-promo_posts, .menu-icon-serwis, .menu-icon-nowe, .menu-icon-silniki, .menu-icon-comments, #toplevel_page_wpcf7, .menu-icon-tools, #wp-admin-bar-new-content, #wp-admin-bar-wpseo-menu, #wp-admin-bar-comments, .update-nag, #toplevel_page_edit-post_type-acf-field-group .wp-submenu li, #menu-appearance, .acf-columns-2 .wp-list-table.widefat tr, #acf-field-group-locations, #mymetabox_revslider_0, #acf-field-group-options {display: none;} .wp-list-table.widefat tr#post-456 {display: block };</style>';
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'remove_links');
}


function cat_for_used_cars() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Kategorie samochodów', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Kategoria samochodów', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Kategoria samochodów', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'Wszystkie samochodów', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nazwa', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Dodaj', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edycja', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_in_menu'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => false,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'usedcars', array( 'uzywane' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cat_for_used_cars', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code :

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'my_func' );
function my_func( $postid )
{
    global $post_type;   
    if ( $post_type != 'uzywane' ) 
        return;

    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $tbl = $prefix.'used_cars';
    $used_cars_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl where post_id = ". $postid );
    if($used_cars_count > 0)
    {
        $wpdb->delete( $tbl, array( 'post_id' => $postid ) );
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!